# Delete Layout Element From Python Dashboard

Tags: python, layout, dashboard

Suppose I have a dashboard app something like this...

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button(
            'Delete HTML Div', 
            id='delete-div-btn'
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                #body
            ], id='div_1'
        ),
    ]
)
```

I want to press the button to delete the html.Div element. I can't really say what I have or haven't tried because I don't really know where to start, except for that I likely need to have a callback function that probably looks something like this...

```
@app.callback(Output('???', '???'),
    [Input('delete-div-btn', "n_clicks")],
    [State('div_1', '???')]
)
```

I don't think I can call div_1 for my output because div_1 is what I'm trying to delete, and that's what's throwing me off.

(note that this is a highly simplified version of a much bigger task that I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't want to get into unnecessary details)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you will have to modify and output the 'children' of the html.Div containing both the button and div_1. You can delete div_1 from the child-container using the callback. First define ID and children of the parent html.Div.

Something like:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(
    id = 'parent_div', #Define ID
    children = [       #Define children
        html.Button(
            'Delete HTML Div', 
            id='delete-div-btn',
            n_clicks = 0          #Set n_clicks to zero
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                #body
            ], id='div_1'
        ),
    ]
)
```

For the callback you could then use your button to delete an element in 'children' of parent_div and return the modified child-container in the function. As 'children' is a list you can use pop(). Notice that the callback will run when you start your app so you have to put an if statement so that the callback does not delete the object at startup (or use PreventUpdate from dash.exceptions). **Also, be sure to set 'n_clicks' to zero when defining the delete-button to prevent 'n_clicks' to be None at app startup.**

Something like:

```
@app.callback(Output('parent_div', 'children'),
              Input('delete-div-btn', 'n_clicks'),
              State('parent_div', 'children'))
def deleteLastElement(n_clicks, container):
  if n_clicks > 0:
    container.pop(-1) # can be used for any index in a children list
  return container
```

Worth thinking about is that this code will eventually delete the delete-button itself if you click it multiple times, depending on the length of the child container and the position of the delete button in the container. So it might not be the best call to have the button in the same container as the objects you want to delete.

A bit late of an answer but maybe this can help someone wondering!